# Getting values from Django model

Tags: django

I have an instance of a Django (1.6) model (let's take `User` for example). I would like to get the field values for that model, like I can do for a `QuerySet`, by calling `QuerySet().values('first_name', 'username')`. Is that possible, or should I just create a dictionary with the required fields?

Edit: A bit more insight into why I need this (maybe there are other workarounds). I want to return a Django model as a JSON response (by using `json.dumps`, not Django's JSON serializer), and so far, I can do that by extending the default Python JSON encoder, and treating Django models specially, by converting them to dictionaries using `model_to_dict`. The problem is that this doesn't get me the related objects, which I need.

Here's my code, for reference:

```
class JsonEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, models.Model):
            return model_to_dict(obj)  # here I'd like to pull some related values

        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pull all related values by default, you can do the following:

```
def default(self, obj):
    if isinstance(obj, models.Model):
        d = model_to_dict(obj)  # here I'd like to pull some related values
        for field in obj._meta.fields:
            if field.rel: # single related object
                d[field.name] = model_to_dict(getattr(obj, field.name))

    return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

This will go one level deep for single related objects, but not for many-to-many relations or reverse foreign keys. Both are possible, but you'll have to find out which methods/attributes on `obj._meta` return the specific fields.

If you only want to retrieve specific fields, you'll have to manually specify and fetch these fields.

Comment: I see. I was hoping for something where I can pass the related fields I want. I will probably end up in making my own `model_to_dict`, because 1 level deep isn't enough. Thanks.